# Detect Google Analytics coded in PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, preg-match, strpos

Oright Guys,

Im looking for a way in PHP to detect the presence of Google Analytics within the source code of a page, retreiveing the page source code via: file_get_contents($url)

I knew analytic code used on the page should be in the format UA-xxxxxxxx-x

so far ive tried:

```
return preg_match("/^ua-\d{4,9}-\d{1,4}$/i", strval($source)) ? true : false;

if(preg_match("/^ua-\d{4,9}-\d{1,4}$/", $source)){

if(strpos($source, "setAccount','UA-")!=''){

if(strpos($source, 'urchin.js')!=''){
```

not the best way to do it, each time it returns false.

any help would be great..

[[ **UPDATE** ]]
Ok so Ive messed around with preg_match a lot,(very frustrating) and after trying a few things the only thing Ive found which will match is

```
if ( preg_match("/\bUA-\b/i", $source) ){
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

this will match the UA- within the Google Analytics code. 
but in order to match better, 
I'm thinking it will need a few things added to the expression.

Whats really needed is to match the first section UA- then match a range of numbers
ie: UA-{range of numbers like 32692708}-{then just 1 number}

if someone can show me a preview of the expression needed that would be great.. :)

Comment: I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for handling html in php

Comment: HI Brad, a Dom parser is a little OTT, 
I have the source code as string, it should just be a matter of searching the string and find any occurrence of the ga code.

Comment: If your requirements are not expanded later, regex should be fine.  Much beyond that though, I think you'll find the DOM parser to be easier.  Also, consider what you will do if/when the Google Analytics are not part of the page in a standard way.  A lot of folks do their GA calls from JavaScript classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are closed with `(preg_match("/^ua-\d{4,9}-\d{1,4}$/", $source)`, just change `^` and `$` with word boundaries `\b` :

```
(preg_match("/\bua-\d{4,9}-\d{1,4}\b/i", $source)
//     here __^^       and here __^^
```